# Pepper plant sprouted with upward growing roots, why?

Tags: vegetables, germination

Okay first off, neither I nor anybody else uprooted the pepper plants. Yesterday, I saw a brown end on two of them which made me think that maybe they sprouted without leaves, since I had a tomato plant sprout without leaves once and the top of its stem was brown until it got a set of leaves. This morning though, I looked again at the pepper plants and I saw roots growing upwards! I have no idea why that would happen. I mean, I knew that plants can move to a certain extent, but uprooting themselves seems like an impossible feat. I was understandably worried, because I have heard that if the roots of a plant are growing upwards, the roots are going to get dried up, too much light exposure and the plant will die.

The stem is still bent down into the soil, but I know that within a day or two, the stem will push up and out of the soil. I checked the pepper plants again this afternoon and now I'm starting to see roots pushing into the soil. But there is still a significant portion of the roots that is up in the light. I have heard of people doing plant surgery to fix this upward growing roots problem, but I don't know how to do plant surgery and I don't want to risk it with my pepper plants.

**So, why would a plant sprout with upward growing roots and are the 2 pepper plants that sprouted with their roots growing upwards going to be okay? I'm growing them indoors in a controlled environment until they are mature enough to safely transplant into the ground.**

Comment: Can you clarify please - are you  talking about seeds which have germinated with the roots going up, or actual pepper plants? A photo would be helpful...

Comment: I’m talking about seeds germinating with the roots going up.